# How to add new field to JSON with jq based on other values

Tags: jq

Assume I have the following JSON:

```
{
  "Address": "myaddress1.com",
  "Port": 6379
},
{
  "Address": "myaddress2.com",
  "Port": 6379
}
```

I want to concatenate both the port and address and also prepend and append some text achieving solely with jq. For example I want the new output to be:

```
{
  "Address": "myaddress1.com",
  "Port": 6379,
  "FullAddress": "redis://myaddress1.com:6379
},
{
  "Address": "myaddress2.com",
  "Port": 6379,
  "FullAddress": "redis://myaddress2.com:6379
}
```

Is this possible with just JQ or do I need to use a scripting language?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that your input file is actually an array of objects, then the following might work for you:

```
$ jq 'map(. + { "FullAddress": "redis://\(.Address):\(.Port)" })' input.json
[
  {
    "Address": "myaddress1.com",
    "Port": 6379,
    "FullAddress": "redis://myaddress1.com:6379"
  },
  {
    "Address": "myaddress2.com",
    "Port": 6379,
    "FullAddress": "redis://myaddress2.com:6379"
  }
]
```

Comment: Nice one, thanks. Just needed to convert my original output into an array

Comment: Instead of converting your input file into an array, you may also call `jq` with the `-s` option to have it read into an array automatically.

Comment: @pmf I don't think that `-s` would work, as each object is separated by a comma (`,`).

Comment: @andlrc Indeed, well spotted! My bad.

Comment: What would my jq command be if this whole array was part of an object say `data : []` 

Like : 
`
  data : [
    {
      "Address": "myaddress1.com",
      "Port": 6379,
      "FullAddress": "redis://myaddress1.com:6379"
    },
    {
      "Address": "myaddress2.com",
      "Port": 6379,
      "FullAddress": "redis://myaddress2.com:6379"
    }
  ] 
` @AndreasLouv